# Angular http обработка

Tags: angularjs, list

У меня есть массив объектов, который приходит с сервера по гет запросу, нужно сделать 2 кнопки, 1я редактирует выбранную позицию, вторая удаляет. Вот кнопки

```
<button ng-dblclick="toggle = !toggle" ng-class="{'editing':toggle}"'>e</button>
<button on-click='deleteTask'>x</button>
```

Вот код скрипта

```
//Удалить пункт
$scope.deleteTask = function(){
    $scope.tasksArr = $scope.tasksArr.filter(function(item){
        return !item.companyName
    })
}
//Изменить пункт
$scope.toggle = false;
    //Изменение данных
$scope.$watch('tasksArr',function(newVal,oldVal){
    if(newVal!=oldVal){
        //localStorage.setItem('tasksArr',JSON.stringify(newVal))
        $http.post('http://avalon.avalonfaltd.com:3090/companies')
        .then(function (response){
                $scope.tasksArr = response.data.success;
        })
        .catch(function (response){
           console.error('error', response.status, response.data);
        });
    }
    },true)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так или как правильно это реализовать